# PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting

Tags: sql, oracle

This is the code I planned to run. I want to generate XML data from the database. So I've used XMLTYPE and REF CURSOR to generate the data.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE XML_TEST AS 
BEGIN
DECLARE
  refcursor SYS_REFCURSOR;
  wxmltype XMLTYPE;
BEGIN
dbms_output.put_line('Input the value of Mess_ID');
  OPEN refcursor FOR SELECT messid, studentname, messname
                            FROM studentsmessdata
                            WHERE messid in &messid; 
  wxmltype:= XMLTYPE(refcursor);
  dbms_output.put_line(wxmltype.getClobVal);
END;
  NULL;
END XML_TEST;`
```

Comment: The code is this
DECLARE
  CURSOR currsor1 IN SELECT messid, studentname, messname
    FROM studentsmessdata
    WHERE messid = &messid;

Comment: That's an incomplete [PL/SQL block](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db112/LNPLS/block.htm) - it has no body. It's nothing to do with the substitution variable. What are you planning to do with the cursor once you've declared it? (It's also 'IS' not 'IN').

Comment: I think you only have an BEGIN too much (before DECLARE) and there is some trailing junk after the first END.

Comment: Please don't invalidate existing answers by completely changing the question. I'm not even sure what you're asking now. Does this still get the same error? You can't prompt for input from within a PL/SQL block, and certainly not from within a procedure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as an anonymous block

```
DECLARE
   messid   studentsmessdata.messid%TYPE;
BEGIN
   mymessid := foo;

   FOR c IN (SELECT messid, studentname, messname
               FROM studentsmessdata
              WHERE messid = mymessid)
   LOOP
      DBMS_OUTPUT.putline (
            'messid: '
         || c.messid
         || ' studentname '
         || c.stdentname
         || ' messname '
         || c.messname);
   END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: That isn't really declaring the cursor (but it's probably better, depending on what the OP actually wants to do with it); and isn't based on user input.

Answer (score 0):

What you're shown is an incomplete [PL/SQL block](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db112/LNPLS/block.htm), as it has [no body](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db112/LNPLS/block.htm#CJACHDGG).

There are lots of examples of blocks in the documentation, [including very high-level ones](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db112/LNPLS/overview.htm#LNPLS141):

> ```
> << label >> (optional)
> DECLARE    -- Declarative part (optional)
>   -- Declarations of local types, variables, & subprograms
>
> BEGIN      -- Executable part (required)
>   -- Statements (which can use items declared in declarative part)
>
> [EXCEPTION -- Exception-handling part (optional)
>   -- Exception handlers for exceptions (errors) raised in executable part]
> END;
> ```

Notice that you've only used the optional declarative part, and not the required executable part.

You've also used `IN` instead of `IS` when declaring your cursor.

So you wold need to do something like:

```
DECLARE
  CURSOR currsor1 IS
    SELECT messid,
      studentname,
      messname
    FROM studentsmessdata
    WHERE messid = &messid; 
BEGIN
  FOR rec IN currsor1 LOOP
    -- do something with rec
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

You can also open the cursor explicitly and fetch into a suitable record type, possibly in a loop - though `messid` is presumably unique so you'll only get one row in the result set anyway. Or you could use [an implicit cursor rather than an explicit one](http://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db112/LNPLS/static.htm#BABDHAED); or since it's (probably) a single row you could `select into` instead of declaring a cursor at all. You need to establish what you plan to do with the data the query returns though.

Comment: I've edited the code to show what I originally wanted to do.